# JSON using android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to add some values to my database from my android application through JSON.

I have used the below code previously with eclipse and worked perfectly, now im trying it using android studio and it isn't working I don't know why!

code:

```
  public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText ID;
EditText fname;
EditText lname;
EditText phone;
Button addbtn;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/add_info.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

String H,Q,C,Ls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID);
    lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);

     H = ID.getText().toString();
     Q = lname.getText().toString();
     C = fname.getText().toString();
     Ls = phone.getText().toString();

    addbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            new CreateNewProduct().execute();

        }
    });


}

class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", H));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", Q));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", C));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", Ls));



        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
               // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminExercise.class);
               // startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}


  }
```

I got this error:

```
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.hatim.maps, PID: 1934
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.hatim.maps.Main2Activity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Main2Activity.java:113)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.hatim.maps.Main2Activity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Main2Activity.java:77)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
   04-14 21:08:36.214 1934-1980/com.example.hatim.maps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't get what is the error?

can someone help please? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your request is not receiving a JSON, may be is an HTML error because the value received starts with html format:

```
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: but i"m sure it's JSON :(

Comment: even when I enter the link in the browser, it will return correctly written JSON!

Comment: I think now I know the reason, it seems to be from the server byethost